# Android custom text on Bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

How to make an editfield

```
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>
```

what is written in it , gets written on the imageview using Canvas ?

I saw many codes and ways , but they are for auto write on the canvas or bitmap their copyrights .. I want what is typed in the editfield gets typed on the canvas ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways to achieve this,

1 - using Canvas.drawText method, example:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500,Bitmap.Config.Alpha_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
c.drawText("Sample Text"); // could be c.drawText(editText.getText());
```

2 -using editText.draw method (recommended)

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500,Bitmap.Config.Alpha_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
et.draw(c);
```

hope it helps, if you have any questions just leave a comment

Comment: not working .. when I type, nothing happens to the canvas or bitmap

Comment: Please post your full code. And which method did you try, the first or the second.

Comment: I used both , but I find the second more efficient but don't work :?